# LINQ-to-Entities get rid of sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-entities, sqlperformance

I am trying to optimize my database now using [Database Engine Tuning Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174215.aspx), and the problem I am facing is that my SQL Profiler trace shows tons of queries performed using `sp_executesql` - and the advisor fails to process those. It seems like these queries come from LINQ-to-Entities I am using, so just curious if there is any way to make LINQ-to-Entities invoke statements directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agree with Adam. Use of `sp_executesql` in entity framework/ADO.net is intentional. The queries are then executed similar to parameterized stored proc and SQL optimizer can reuse the query plan.

If you are looking to tune your DB, you should consider these queries as well. I suggest you,take a backup of your DB, capture the queries using replay trace template (in your SQL profiler) , restore your DB, run your tuning advisor settings its workload to this trace

Answer (score 6):

LINQ/.NET runs SQL queries by sending them as `sp_executesql` calls to SQL server. However, **Database Engine Tuning Advisor** can't parse such, by **SQL Server Profiler**, captured statements, so the result of the tuning session will be poor.

This is how I 'unbox' the `sp_executesql` statements before feeding them to Database Engine Tuning Advisor so it can analyze them correctly.

1. After you've run (or opened an existing) tuning session in **SQL Server Profiler**, use *File>Export>Extract SQL Server Events>Extract Transact-SQL Events...* to save a .SQL file containing all SQL statements.
2. Open the .SQL file (in e.g. **Notepad++ 6** - http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and run the following Find & Replacement Regular Expression to unbox all `sp_executesql` statements to plain TSQL. Find: *`^EXEC[\s]+SP_EXECUTESQL[\s]+[N]*'((''|[^'])*)'[\s]*,[\s]*[N]*'((''|[^'])*)'[\s]*,[\s]*([^\n]+)$`* Replace: *`BEGIN\nDECLARE \3\nSELECT \5\n\1\nEND`*
3. Next, use the 'unboxed' .SQL filed that we've just constructed in **Database Engine Tuning Advisor** to find out what indexes you neeed to add.

Happy tuning! Please note that I've selected Notepad++ 6 (or above) since it has a pretty good Regular Expression implementation, other texteditors may fail at running the expression above.

Comment: why aren't you at the top? this simple find and replace really did the trick. Except the EF uses same variable names for every procedure calls. But this ^ really helpful. Thanks mate!

Comment: Update to "Find" expression: ^EXEC[\s]+SP_EXECUTESQL[\s]+[N]*'((''''|''|[^']*)*)'[\s]*,[\s]*[N]*'((''''|''|[^']*)*)'[\s]*,[\s]*([^\n]+)$

Answer (score 3):

That is just an artifact of how RPC calls are shown in profiler. There are two main types of client requests: Language (type 0x01) and RPC (type 0x03), as documented by the [Free TDS protocol documentation](http://www.freetds.org/tds.html#requests). When the call is a SQL batch with parameters, the RPC call will be of type 0x03 with length 0x0A which is a shortcut for `sp_executesql`.

So you see, what really happens is that when a client, *any client*, submits a batch that contains parameters, it will appear as if `sp_executesql` is being called. This is true with ODBC, with OleDB, SqlClient, Sql Native Client, as I said, *any* client. So is not Entity Framework, nor ADO.Net that actually calls sp_executesql (in fact, the procedure is not even really called, although the requests executes as if it was called. Is complicated...). It is an artifact of the protocol that happens anytime you add an `@parameter` to your request.

Comment: Thanks for explanation - it clarifies things quite a bit.. Now I understand what's going on!

Answer (score 2):

The usage of `sp_executesql` is an ADO.NET effect, not something specific to the Entity Framework. As far as I am aware, there's no way to instruct it not to use that stored procedure.